# Using chessboard package, how to render "black" squares in solid gray?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chess, chessboard

In latex chessboard package, by default, black squares are rendered with hatch patten. I want them in solid gray.
[image]
My several attempts failed, chessboard.pdf is not helpful here. The programming model is not clear, so I gave up. Need help. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[LSB,LSBC3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skaknew]{skak,chessboard}
\begin{document}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}
\chessboard
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[LSB,LSBC4,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skaknew]{skak,chessboard}
\begin{document}
    \setboardfontcolors{
        blackfieldmask=gray!30}
\setchessboard{boardfontencoding=LSBC4,setfontcolors,showmover=false}
\chessboard
\end{document}
```

Code with light gray. See setboardfontcolors.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks! Difficult getting through the documentation. +1

Comment: Life is cool because of you guys at StackExchange, a million thanks.

Comment: I will accept this as answer. It gives control over color. Also thanks to DJP for giving a quick solution.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation on CTAN is [here](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chessboard/chessboard.pdf). I found something like what you wanted on page 34. I modified your code using `boardfontencoding=LSBC4` to get the result below.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[LSB,LSBC4,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skaknew]{skak,chessboard}
\begin{document}
\setchessboard{boardfontencoding=LSBC4,setfontcolors,showmover=false}
\chessboard
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The solution works, but can I set a lighter shade of gray? Say gray!30.

Comment: I tested color properties from the documentation and ran into transparency issues, and gave up. Strange, a font change is producing a different color.

Comment: Sango found the fix to modify the gray color and posted it in their answer.