# Draw king chess on chess board

Tags: chessboard

[image: Help me, how to draw this one]

Help me, how to draw the king on chess board.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show what you have already tried so far. You'll find several examples on how to typeset chessboards and positions on this site, e.g as a starter https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29603/where-to-start-typesetting-chess-with-tex

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possibility. I've modified Sango's code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507755/using-chessboard-package-how-to-render-black-squares-in-solid-gray/507759#507759).

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[LSB,LSBC4,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skaknew]{skak,chessboard}
\begin{document}
    \setboardfontcolors{
        blackfieldmask=OliveGreen!80}
\setchessboard{boardfontencoding=LSBC4,setfontcolors,showmover=false}
\chessboard[setpieces={Ke4},label=false]
\end{document}
```

The output is shown running in Gummi:
[image]

The line `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` gives access to more color names. The code `label=false` removes the labelling of the ranks and files. The capital letter gives white king while `ke4` would put a black king on e4.